# why is this Java Proxy Server very slow?

Tags: java, multithreading, proxy, reverse-proxy, java-threads

I need a `Java Proxy Server` that let me connect to [localhost:9318] through [localhost:9418], like:

```
[my browser] -> [localhost:9418] -> [localhost:9318]
```

for that I tried this code:

http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Network-Protocol/Asimpleproxyserver.htm

```
package com.example.proxyserver;

import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        try {
            String host = "localhost";
            int remoteport = 9318;
            int localport = 9418;
            // Print a start-up message
            System.out.println("Starting proxy for " + host + ":" + remoteport + " on port " + localport);
            // And start running the server
            runServer(host, remoteport, localport); // never returns
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println(e);
        }
    }

    /**
     * runs a single-threaded proxy server on the specified local port. It never
     * returns.
     */
    public static void runServer(String host, int remoteport, int localport) throws IOException {
        // Create a ServerSocket to listen for connections with
        ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(localport);

        final byte[] request = new byte[1024];
        byte[] reply = new byte[4096];

        while (true) {
            Socket client = null, server = null;
            try {
                // Wait for a connection on the local port
                client = ss.accept();

                final InputStream streamFromClient = client.getInputStream();
                final OutputStream streamToClient = client.getOutputStream();

                // Make a connection to the real server.
                // If we cannot connect to the server, send an error to the
                // client, disconnect, and continue waiting for connections.
                try {
                    server = new Socket(host, remoteport);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(streamToClient);
                    out.print("Proxy server cannot connect to " + host + ":" + remoteport + ":\n" + e + "\n");
                    out.flush();
                    client.close();
                    continue;
                }

                // Get server streams.
                final InputStream streamFromServer = server.getInputStream();
                final OutputStream streamToServer = server.getOutputStream();

                // a thread to read the client's requests and pass them
                // to the server. A separate thread for asynchronous.
                Thread t = new Thread() {
                    public void run() {
                        int bytesRead;
                        try {
                            while ((bytesRead = streamFromClient.read(request)) != -1) {
                                streamToServer.write(request, 0, bytesRead);
                                streamToServer.flush();
                            }
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                        }

                        // the client closed the connection to us, so close our
                        // connection to the server.
                        try {
                            streamToServer.close();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                        }
                    }
                };

                // Start the client-to-server request thread running
                t.start();

                // Read the server's responses
                // and pass them back to the client.
                int bytesRead;
                try {
                    while ((bytesRead = streamFromServer.read(reply)) != -1) {
                        streamToClient.write(reply, 0, bytesRead);
                        streamToClient.flush();
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                }

                // The server closed its connection to us, so we close our
                // connection to our client.
                streamToClient.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.err.println(e);
            } finally {
                try {
                    if (server != null)
                        server.close();
                    if (client != null)
                        client.close();
                }
                catch (IOException e) {

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This code works but it is very slow.

Do you know what do I need to do in order to increase the speed?

Or maybe do you know about another Java Proxy Server code that be fast?

Thanks!

Comment: Please characterize "very slow".  Is it slow accepting connections?   (I note that it will only handle one connection at a time ...) Is it slow sending / receiving data?  (You could try using NIO ...).  Is it slow *compared to some other proxy server implementation*?  Have you profiled the code?  Have you determined whether the slowness is in the Java code, the OS, the network, the client or the server?

Comment: In short, there are many possible reasons why this proxy might be slow, and a lot of them are unrelated to the code ...